# optimize two ternary operation in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-operator, ternary

I still haven't found anyway for optimizing this code, I think there should be something missing from the code, please help me to make it shorter.

firstWay:

```
     fromAddress
                    Get.isDarkMode
                        ? isCart
                            ? Images.emptyCartDark
                            : Images.noDataFoundDark
                        : isCart
                            ? Images.emptyCartLight
                            : Images.noDataFoundLight,
```

second way:

```
                    isCart
                        ? Get.isDarkMode
                            ? Images.emptyCartDark
                            : Images.emptyCartLight
                        : Get.isDarkMode
                            ? Images.noDataFoundDark
                            : Images.noDataFoundLight,
```

Comment: why don't you make it a getter or a function to return that?

Comment: I think either of your ways are fine. No need for optimizing

Comment: You can put your dark assets inside a DarkAssetClass (linked to the darkTheme) and same for a LightAssetsClass and then put some getter. Seems good. 
Using extension could be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Please create function like below.

```
String getImage(bool isCart, bool isDarkMode) {
  return Images['${isCart ? 'Cart' : 'NoDataFound'}${isDarkMode ? 'Dark' : 'Light'}'];
}
```